# scrollview does not change contentOffset

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

i have a large horizontal scrollview with different views on it. 
The scrolling works fine, but now i added buttons to go the previous of next page.
I assumed that this code would do the trick because i already used it a few times:

```
-(void)goBack{ 
    CGPoint offset = [self.scrollview contentOffset];
    NSLog(@"Offset : %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(offset));

    [self.scrollview setContentOffset:huidigeOffset];

    CGPoint offset2 = [self.scrollview contentOffset];
    NSLog(@"Offset2 : %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(offset2));}
```

However this does not work, for the first en last NSLog i get this result:

```
2011-05-03 09:41:42.066 Elektrozine_V6[1668:207] Offset : {0, 0}
2011-05-03 09:41:42.066 Elektrozine_V6[1668:207] Offset2 : {0, 0}
```

In the viewDidLoad the offset is set to:

```
2011-05-03 09:41:38.497 Elektrozine_V6[1668:207] Offset : {600, 0}
```

This part is correct , i actually set it for this amount with this:

```
    [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(2141, 0)];
    scrollview.contentOffset = CGPointMake((int)600, 0);

    huidigeOffset = [self.scrollview contentOffset];
```

Does anyone have a clue why it won't work in the method i have made?
I searched a lot of sites  but nobody has a real answer to it

Kind regards !

Snowy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go previous page then you need to call scrollRectToVisible method instead setContentOffSet.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i tried this: 
'[scrollview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10) animated:YES];' 

but is doesn't do anything, i am sure that xCode goes into the method because of the NSLog i put there.

grtz snowy

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)goBack{ 

    NSLog(@"Offset : %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollview.contentOffset));
    [scrollview setContentOffset:huidigeOffset];
    NSLog(@"Offset2 : %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollview.contentOffset));
}
```

Comment: I get the same result in the console as above, 
grtz snowy

Comment: you access self.scrollview in one case and just scrollview in other. Make it uniform and try

Comment: when i make it uniform it is still the same result , {0,0}. when i try the solution from user dks1725 it also does nothing.
grtz

Comment: see if the content offset changes in the delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll:`

Comment: i can not get access to this method in my file, is that possible?

Comment: Implement `UIScrollViewDelegate`

Comment: ok sorry, euhm i am still getting that the offset has not been changed

Comment: Is the delegate method called?

Comment: then how can you say that the offset has not changed. If u implement UIScrollViewDelegate and add scrollView.delegate=self; you will get into the method

Comment: ok thanks for the information, i get it now, i will search further on it :) thank you very much for your time !